# git-hub for windows revert

Tags: git, github

I am in a very stupid situation now. Playing with git-hub for windows I have reverted my last two local commits, and I can't undo this (revert command). A lot of code have gone. Is it posible restore reverted commits? I am new at git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No worries. You can get your code back.

One way is to revert the commits that reverted your work. List your last commits using `git log` then `git revert` your previous reverts.

Another is to reset your master to a point before your reverts. This will be the cleanest way if the two last commands were the two reverts. Then you can do

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

As Srdjan Grubor points out, if you cannot find your commits using `git log` you can go look for them in `git reflog` which shows you where your HEAD has been lately, even after such commands as `git reset`.

Answer (score 3):

Klas is correct and you could also look into

```
git reflog
```

command to get your history back